# How to Search through my api and see if the id matches with another id - ionic1/angularjs1

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, if-statement, ionic-framework

I am trying to search through my api and see if one of the ids that are in the api matches another id, and if so it should create a variable and add a field to that variable the field it should add it from the row with the same id.

but it is not adding it to that variable

You can see my code here:

```
.controller('PlayAod', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$stateParams', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams) {
    $scope.title = 'Sample Company';
    $scope.apiusername = 'hoy';
    $scope.apipassword = '076fdf74936ebae00e7949a80f61f985';
    $scope.aodid = $stateParams.id;
    $scope.stream = "";

    $http.get('http://tvstartup.biz/mng-channel/vpanel/api/audios.php?user=' + $scope.apiusername + '&pass=' + $scope.apipassword).success(function (data) {
        $scope.aodhls = data.audios;
        if (data.audios.id == $scope.aodid) {
            $scope.stream = data.audios.hls_stream;
            $scope.play = function() {
            window.cndStream.stop();
            window.cndStream.play($scope.stream);
        }
    }
    });

    $scope.pause = function() {
        window.cndStream.pause();
    }
    $scope.stop = function() {
        window.cndStream.stop();
    }

}])
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar bar-dark">
    <h1 class="title">{{ title }} - Photos</h1>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-content>
{{ stream }} {{ aodid }}
</ion-content>
```

Please Help Thank you

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: what is the issue you facing? I am not clear

Comment: i can not get it to check the ids @Ved

Comment: is You apiCall working.? Can you post response data?

Comment: yes my apicall is working @ved

Comment: is this  if (data.audios.id == $scope.aodid) { not working for you?

Comment: no it does not work @Ved

Comment: can you show me the data?

Comment: what do you mean? @Ved

Comment: show me value of    $scope.aodhls, data.audios;

Comment: you can get if from the api above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem is related to the fact that data.audios is an array of objects and does not have a property 'id'.  Your call

```
if (data.audios.id == $scope.aodid)
```

Is then considering whether $scope.aodid == undefined; which I imagine it is not, so the if block never runs.

Place the following call in your success bock to see more info:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
```

Depending on what you are trying to do, you either need to get more specific on yout $http.get call or you need to find the object within the data.audios array that has the 'id' you are after.

Comment: i will try it ok